# jaxb2-maven-plugin generate only a select few classes

Tags: jaxb, xsd, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I have a XSD file that contains many many types, most of which I do not need. However, I do not have the ability to currently trim it down to just what I need. So that being said, Is there a way to tell the jaxb2-maven-plugin to only generate a specific set of types or classes (a whitelist if you will), so that it's not auto generating the 1000+ classes?

Thanks in advance!